# Will my earnings halal if I use a computer that ever used to do something haram?

Tags: halal-haram

*Assalamu alaikum*

I want to make money online with my computer that I used to watch porn, play online gambling, and other haram things. So, will my earnings halal?

Comment: Why shouldn't they be?

Answer (score -1):

WaAlykum alsalam,
you have to create a new log in user in your computer and use it only for legitimate halal purposes.

Answer (score -2):

> So, will my earnings halal?

It depends on the nature of your business. If you are, for example, investing in haram industries like vulture funds and fossil fuels - then your earnings will not be halal.